# Can I slow down or stop physics in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode

It seems to me that a framework that aims for simplicity would have that method so, and not to remove every node from the physics accounting like I'm doing now:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"live" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){
        [node removeFromParent];
}];
```

I'm sorry if this is a noob question, I've just started working with SpriteKit. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It has "that method". If you look in the [SKPhysicsWorld reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013034) you'll find the `speed` property. Speed = 0 means paused.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to pause the scene, you can just do:

self.paused = YES;

which will proliferate across all nodes you've added to the scene as well.

This same flag can be set on individual nodes. Node that paused nodes don't play well with collision detection, and won't run any action-based-animations until you've unpaused them.

self.physicsWorld has a few properties that may be helpful in "slowing down physics" -

self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-4.9);

would be 50% of real-world gravity, for instance.  The actual numbers don't really matter much, so definitely tweak the gravity value until it feels right. This is vastly preferred over the next option you can play with:

self.physicsWorld.speed = x;

where the default value of x is 1, and 0 would be the same as pausing all physics calculations.

changing gravity is preferred because it won't also make things bounce slower (for instance).

Answer (score 1):

SKNode has several methods to remove children.

You can see them here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW40

You can do...

```
removeAllChildren
```

Or

```
removeChildrenInArray:
```

Etc...

**edit**

Wait, what are you asking? Your title and question don't match.

Comment: I was asking about the pshysics itself actually and wether it can or not be slowed and/or stopped

Comment: as in how to slow the gravity pull down